# OpenCV convertTo slow

Tags: c++, performance, image-processing, opencv

I have one image `cv::Mat` `fooImage` 1000*1000 pixels in `CV_32F` format.

Now I want to show the image, I use

```
fooImage.convertTo(displayImage,CV_8UC1)
```

However, it takes about 5ms just for this line. Is this normal?? How can I quickly convert a `CV_32F` Mat image to `CV_8UC1`?

Thanks!

Comment: Intel Xeon CPU E5-2690 windows 7 64 bits

Comment: The time has come when taking 5 ms to convert 4 million bytes to 1 million bytes in a different format is considered slow. How much time you expect to perform this ? I suspect OpenCV is going to be too slow for you. Also, be sure to measure these timings very accurately.

Comment: While float to int conversions are slow, the timings you listed correspond to more than 10.000 cycles/conversion - Which can't be true. So you either measure it wrongly or your build is not release mode or something else is wrong

Comment: Notice that it isn't only a matter of taking 4 red apples and randomly transforming it into 1 orange to your friend, you have to represent these 4 apples as good as you can with only one 1 green apple (because you like your friend, let's say that). One way to do so is by considering all your original one million apples, find the largest one, the smallest one, subtract these sizes, raise it to -1 and multiply by 2^(APPLE-BIT-DEPTH). If you know your apples very well, you can simplify this but the basic conversion stil needs to be done for each apple, so your friend gets green apples.

Comment: re @mmpg: I was expecting less than 1ms... I used time.h, clock_t, time1 = clock(); to calcualte the time.

Comment: re @sammy: I was using the release version. I used time.h, time = clock() to measure the time. I don't know whether it is accurate or not..

Comment: @UserKiwi that is not accurate timing by any standards.

Comment: @mmgp, thank you for pointing this out. Do you have any suggestions on this? Thank you!

Comment: You are after high resolution timers. See http://www.songho.ca/misc/timer/timer.html, for example, as a starting point.

Comment: @mmgp, based on the link, the precision of my clock() is 1ms... not bad

Answer (score 2):

That sounds slow but convertTo() probably isn't particularly optomised to use SSE2 or anything.

You are reading 4Mb from RAM, allocating 1Mb, doing 4Million floating point ops and writing 1Mb back to RAM so a millisecond isn't unreasonable.

You could write a simple loop to convert the image data into uchar yourself by simply multiplying each value by 255.0

Are you including the time to display the image? YOu are creating a "displayImage" that is still 8bit greyscale, this will have to be converted into a RGB or RGBA image when it is displayed

Comment: I don't see how multiplying each value by 255 is correct. You certainly cannot represent 424242.424242 * 255 in an unsigned byte.

Comment: I guess Martin assumed that the values are in the interval [0.0f,1.0f], because that is how floating point images are stored by convention.

Comment: thank you @Martin Beckett, my problem got solved because of your comments, but the issue with convertTo is still not solved. At the beginning, I just want to display the image, it turns out the function imshow, automatically scaled the image by 255 if it is in CV_32F, so I was thinking to convert it to CV_8UC1. Based on your comments, I divided all the CV_32F images by 255, then directly use imshow, I can display the image. So the 5ms for convertTo is saved. But still I don't understand why a simple conversion can take 5 ms....

Comment: this 5ms didn't include the display. it is like this: time1 = clock(); fooImage.convertTo(displayImage,CV_8UC1); time2 = clock(); time = time2-time1.

Comment: @UserKiwi, imshow() just calls convertTo(). If you care you could do some more timing tests, it may be that clock() only updates it's answer every 5ms - try calling convertTo() 100x in a loop and time that